# Kinect Save joint data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, kinect

I've looked at a few tutorials and articles on this about saving Kinect skeleton data but none of them seem to be working , Basically at the moment I have a timer which at set intervals (2.5 secs) takes screenshots , as well as/instead of taking the screenshot I want to read all of the join information into an array and/or save the coordinates (x,y) into a text file , When these motions are saved to the file I then want to follow the same steps to make a fresh set of coordinates and compare the two.

Answer (score 0):

The [Kinect Toolbox](http://kinecttoolbox.codeplex.com/) provides this function out of the box.  It is an open source library you can include in your application, or could examine the code to get ides on how to proceed.

If you wish to roll your own, you can set your timer to save the `Skeleton` or a subset of the `Joint` information into a custom class that include a zero-based time stamp.  You can then put these into a `List`.  When you're ready to save, you can do a binary save or save it XML with a serializer.

Comment: I've tried adding Kinect toolbox from 2 seperate versions nd neither of them will work , I add the .dll to references but I still cannot use it in the "usings"

Comment: I just downloaded the latest Kinect Toolbox archive, loaded the DLL into the References and was able to type `using Kinect.Toolbox;` with autocomplete working and no errors.  Perhaps there is something incorrect with your Visual Studio environment that is conflicting.  Maybe try to include it in a new project for testing, or look at the demo included with Kinect Toolbox to see what environment differences there are.

Comment: No luck , its actually working in some of my classes just not in my .xaml.cs , I've abandoned saving the skeletal joint positions and I'm just going to take screenshots and pun a pixel by pixel compare